# Is there a way to disable a tabindex on a wpf control?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a row of 5 expanders on the top of my page that I do not want to get to using the tab button. There is currently no tabindex but for whatever reason I'm able to get to it using the tab button. I've tried using IsTabStop = False and I've tried = True but neither make a difference. I've also tried setting TabIndex=0 but that didn't work either.

```
 <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding ScrollTop_IsExpanded}" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"  ExpandDirection="Right" />
 <Label Margin="2,0,2,0" Content="Top" FontSize="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

Comment: Try `Focusable="False"`.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your reply. That didn't work unfortunately, it still hits the expander when I press the tab button. I've even tried setting a tabindex to it to see if I could change the order and that didn't work either. Is it possible there is something in the code behind blocking it?

Comment: you could try KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"** in your Expander

```
 <Expander KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" IsExpanded="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="True" ExpandDirection="Right" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"
```